# Angular / Type script how to print a value from json object

Tags: angular, typescript

I want to print in my front page from json object.

For example; {'name': 'Jay' , 'empno' : 'e011'}
and i want to print only values of name and empno as below

Jay

e011

Answer (score 0):

You will need to parse the data first using var obj = JSON.parse(your json object variable)
Then access like obj['name'] and obj['empno']

Comment: it says cannot find name JSON. Is 'JSON' keyword support to type script?

Comment: Yes it is supported. Which angular and typescript version are you using?

Comment: `JSON.parse` is redundant if the JSON object variable passed in is already a valid JavaScript object and should only be used if the value passed in is a string that contains JSON data.

Answer (score 0):

```
 let data= {
     'name': 'Jay',
     'empno' : 'e011'
    };

console.log(data.name);

console.log(data.empno);
```